# How can I pass a parameter into a resource without changing the route?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Basically, I need to get one parameter from my angular app to be used in my nodeJS service. I have a GET request that looks like this:

```
resource: $resource(nodeRoute + '/test'. {}, {
    query: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                offset: '@offset',
                limit: '@limit'
            },
            isArray: true,
            url: ohio.resources.netreg + '/registrations'
    },
}
```

Where 'offset' and 'limit' are what I am trying to pass in, via this call in my routeprovider's resolve block:

```
.when('/'. {
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    title: 'test',
    resolve: {
        registrations: ['thisResource', function(thisResource){
            return thisResource.resource.query(0, 2).$promise
        ]);
    }
```

Where I'm trying to pass the values 0 and 2 in for offset and limit, so that I can then go on to use those values in my server side node stuff. This works great if, in my resource, I hard code offset and limit to some values, but I need to update these values, thus this needs to work like I'm trying to do above. What am I missing? I'm assuming the @ character only works if I have a route like /:offset/:limit, but I can't really do that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
resource: $resource(nodeRoute + '/test/:offset/:limit' {}, {
query: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
            offset: '@offset',
            limit: '@limit'
        },
        isArray: true,
        url: ohio.resources.netreg + '/registrations'
  },
}
```

and in resolve use this

```
 resolve: {
    registrations: ['thisResource', function(thisResource){
        return thisResource.resource.query({offset:0, limit:2}).$promise
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work. It may also be worth mentioning that /:offset/:limit in the resource don't seem to be necessary, which is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to specify the parameters via a get, then another option is using a post where you can specify params without necessarily appending to your url.

so in your node js you can access the post params like

```
postrouter.post('/test', function (req, res){
      //you can access your post params via req.body
      console.log(req.body)//gives you your passed objects
})
```

then in your resource instead of a get it'll be a post.
in your controller you can pass your params like this in your resolve.

```
    resolve: {
    registrations: ['thisResource', function(thisResource){
        return thisResource.resource.query({offset:0, limit:2}).$promise
    ]);
}
```

hope it helps.!!